# How can I arrive at $a^6$ for expression $\frac{6a^2*a^0}{2a^{-4}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am given the expression $\frac{6a^2*a^0}{2a^{-4}}$ and am told to simplify. The solution provided is $a^6$.

For the numerator I'm aware that $a^0$ = 1 which reduces the numerator to just $6a^2$.

For the denominator, I'm aware that the negative rule of exponents allows me to rewrite $2a^{-4}$ as $2 * \frac{1}{a^4}$

But I'm unable to see how to reduce the whole expression to $a^6$?

---

Comments are pointing out that the solution is incorrect. Here's a screen shot of the question and answer in case I've taken the syntax down incorrectly.
[image]

This is viewable on the free online textbook [here](https://cnx.org/contents/E6wQevFf@11.1:RZUxkOcn@9/Rational-Expressions#Example_01_06_01) under the practice section for exponents and scientific notation.

Comment: Doesn't look right to me; should be $3a^6$.

Comment: The net exponent for $a$ is $2+0-(-4)=6$. Add exponents from factors in the numerator, subtract exponents from factors in the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$3\cdot a^{2-(-4)}$$ and so we get $$3a^{6}$$ and it must be $$a\neq 0$$

Answer (score 3):

Having arrived at $\frac{6a^2}{2a^{-4}}$, multiply by $a^4$ on top and bottom to get
$$\frac{6a^2×a^4}{2a^{-4}×a^4}=\frac{6a^6}{2a^0}=3a^6$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{6a^2*a^0}{2a^{-4}} = \frac{6a^2*1}{2a^{-4}} = {3a^2}*{a^{-(-4)}} = 3a^6$$

The second transition is due to $\dfrac{1}{a^{-4}} = a^{-(-4)} = a^4$.